# how to write a copy function for an array?

Tags: arrays, c, copy

How to write a copy function for an array of size 2? using `c`
I want it so i can pass it to a generic code
this is the define:

```
/** Key element data type for map container */
typedef void *MapKeyElement;
```

this is the copy function that i wrote:

```
MapKeyElement gameCopyKey(MapKeyElement array_to_copy)
 {
if(!array_to_copy)
{
 
   return NULL ;
}
int** array=malloc(sizeof(**array));
if(!array)
{
return NULL;
}
int *tmp=(int*)array_to_copy;
  *array[0]= tmp[0];
  *array[1]= tmp[1];
return array;
}
```

but i don't know if it's the write way to do it or not ?
does anyone have an idea?

Comment: At least `int** array=malloc(sizeof(**array));` looks wrong. It should be `int** array=malloc(sizeof(*array) * 2);` to allocate `array[0]` and `array[1]`. Also don't forget to initialize the elements to some valid address before dereferencing them.

Answer (score 2):

You must tell the function what size the array elements are. You can do this either by making the type a complete type rather than `void`:

```
typedef WhateverMyElementTypeIs *MapKeyElement;

MapKeyElement CopyThisArray(MapKeyElement Array)
{
    MapKeyElement NewArray = malloc(2 * sizeof *NewArray);
    if (NewArray)
        memcpy(NewArray, Array, 2 * sizeof *NewArray);
    return NewArray;
}
```

or by passing the size to the function:

```
typedef void *MapKeyElement;

MapKeyElement CopyThisArray(MapKeyElement Array, size_t ElementSize)
{
    MapKeyElement NewArray = malloc(2 * ElementSize);
    if (NewArray)
        memcpy(NewArray, Array, 2 * ElementSize);
    return NewArray;
}
```

`memcpy` is declared in `<string.h>`, and `size_t` is declared in `<stddef.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in C to avoid the size of data being copied from the copying function: it is passed either as a property of the data type that you want to copy, or as an explicit argument:

```
void* copy2(void* array2, size_t szElement)
{
    void* res = malloc(2*szElement);
    // do your NULL check here...
    memcpy(res, array2, 2*szElement);
    return res;
}
```

You could hide the part that figures out the size into a macro, though:

```
#define COPY2(x) copy2((x), sizeof((x)[0]))
```

This macro must be passed an array of a specific type that you are copying, not a `void*`.

Here is how you would use this macro:

```
int ia[2] = {321, 789};
int* ic = COPY2(ia);
struct foo {
    char* a;
    char* b;
} sa[2] = {
    {"hello", "world"},
    {"one", "two"}
}, *sc = COPY2(sa);
printf("%d %d\n", ic[0], ic[1]);
printf("%s %s\n%s %s\n", sc[0].a, sc[0].b, sc[1].a, sc[1].b);
```

Note how `COPY2(ia)` and `COPY2(sa)` look the same, but they pass `copy2` different `sizeof` values based on the element type of `ia` vs. `sa`.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/2jeazz)